# How to parse collection of PEM certs

Tags: go, ssl, x509, pem

I have a collection of pem certs in a string, that I want to bind to a TLS endpoint, how can I effectively convert them to CRT files (i.e.public.crt) and key file (i.e. private.key), for binding it to the endpoint:

Input string:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE3oydueOANJHhvL3yvJdTphoev5GO7go+ByYOO/l54u5O2PxMeX+AjAb6Axmq
livIuhw=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3oydueOANJHhvL3yvJdTphoev5GO7go+ByYOO/l54u5O2PxMeX+AjAb6Axmq
livIuhw=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3oydueOANJHhvL3yvJdTphoev5GO7go+ByYOO/l54u5O2PxMeX+AjAb6Axmq
asdsa312asdsadasdsad=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My code to bind would be:

```
https_r := mux.NewRouter()
err_https := http.ListenAndServeTLS(serviceEndpoint, "/etc/pki/tls/certs/public.crt", "/etc/pki/tls/certs/private.key", https_r)
    if err_https != nil {
        log.Fatal("Web server (HTTPS): ", err_https)
    }
```

I have tried two approaches:

1. I tried to [decode](https://golang.org/src/encoding/pem/pem.go?s=2505:2553#L76) it to a PEM block, but it only reads one of the certs and drops the rest.
2. I tried to create a [CertPool](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/cert_pool.go?s=3200:3264#L118) out of the string, but it also loads one of the cert.

Ideally, I would not like to perform a bunch of string parsing, which would be prone to break.

Any other way would highly be appreciated.

Comment: You can manually split them into different files or use go to read them. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @Marc for the response, edited the question.

Comment: Use [tls.X509KeyPair](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#X509KeyPair) (you can pass the same bytes for both arguments) and assign the return value to [the Certificates field](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.Certificates) of [the tls config](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.TLSConfig). You can then pass empty strings to ListenAndServeTLS.

Comment: Have you've tried to simply use your file as both certificate and key? I'm not sure about Go, but for example OpenSSL will simply pick what it needs from the file (i.e. list of certificates for one argument, the private key for another) and ignore the rest.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that did the trick when I have the private key/ public key in the same string. But I might have more in it, essentially the chain of the issuers. Worst case, I would have to store those separately, and append them to &tls.Config.Certificates. Any other direction you would suggest?

Comment: You're supposed to provide the whole chain leading to the trusted root, be it in a file or byte slice. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to decode it to a PEM block, but it only reads one of the certs and drops the rest.

The trick is to handle the rest of the PEM blocks. It is returned in `pem.Decode` seconds result. Here is how it can be done:

```golang
    for block, rest := pem.Decode(data); block != nil; block, rest = pem.Decode(rest) {
        switch block.Type {
        case "CERTIFICATE":
            cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            // Handle certificate
            fmt.Printf("%T %#v\n", cert, cert)

        case "PRIVATE KEY":
            key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            // Handle private key
            fmt.Printf("%T %#v\n", key, key)

        default:
            panic("unknown block type")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I think it should be case "RSA PRIVATE KEY"